# Solution to fetch postal code based on location in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google Places Autocomplete API to fetch postal code after user inputs location details using place_id..
The problem is I dont receive postal code in response of every input. For e.g if I try to fetch postal code using following request -https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJgSzDPOm25zsRgqHV-CAHRQE&key=API_KEY

This requests returns postal code in response.

At the same time when I replace the place_id with this value: ChIJYTDaPDOp5zsRw6VVgelKUUw

I dont receive postal code in response.

This shows that google doesnt send postal code in response in every case. I would like to know about any API or solution where I could be able to receive postal code in every response.

Comment: I have the same issue essentially.  What I do is take the lat and lng returned for the place and reverse geocode. For some reason it works extremely well.

Comment: For every lat,lng you ALWAYS receive a postal code? Also this will again add one more request response loop in the flow.. I would be making 4 such calls continuously.. I suppose this might not be a good approach..

Comment: yes, always. I'm doing this client side and so I'm not worried (yet) about the volume of requests.